TDD for Azure Devops Extension with mocked task in Typescript
I am developing a Azure Devops Extension (task) in TypeScript with Visual Studio Code. I am used to test driven development (TDD) or at least to writing unit tests to develop major parts of an application. Usually I write C# code.
I set up a task according to Add a custom pipelines task extension/Microsoft and added tests as proposed:
My _suite.ts has this content:
it('should succeed with simple inputs', function(done: Mocha.Done) {
 let tp: string = path.join(__dirname, 'success.js');
 let tr: ttm.MockTestRunner = new ttm.MockTestRunner(tp);

  tr.runAsync().then(() => {
     // 4) Assertions     
     assert.equal(tr.succeeded, true, 'should have succeeded');
     done();
  }).catch((error) => {
     done(error);
  });
});

whereas the abbreviated success.js is:
import ma = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/mock-answer');
import tmrm = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/mock-run');

// 1) test setup/mocks
let taskPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'index.js');
let tmr: tmrm.TaskMockRunner = new tmrm.TaskMockRunner(taskPath);

// 2) set test input data
tmr.setInput('samplestring', 'human');

// 3) execute index.js
tmr.run(); 

My problem:
Good tests should be easy to read and should be in one function in a structure similar to:
it('should succeed with simple inputs', function(done: Mocha.Done) {
  // 1) test setup/mocks
  let tr: ttm.MockTestRunner = new ttm.MockTestRunner(tp);
  // set some answers in the mock
  // 2) set test input data
  tr.setInput('samplestring', 'human'); // doesn't work
  // 3) execute production code
  // tr.setCode('index.js') // doesn't work
  tr.runAsync().then(() => {
     // 4) Assertions     
     assert.equal(tr.succeeded, true, 'should have succeeded');
     done();
  }).catch((error) => {
     done(error);
  });
});

The test structure that is proposed by Microsoft puts 1+4 together in a file and 2+3 and adds  code around to make it work. This makes the test hard to read and hard to write tests.
How can I rewrite the tests so I have everything in a function without loosing the ability to set task input or mock answers azure-pipelines-task-lib/mock-answer?
What I found out:
In Microsofts task repo they sometimes wrap the task input values as environment variables, ie. they set some special env variables in the _suite.ts by process.env[shared.TestEnvVars.someTaskInput] = 'namespacefrominput'; , read and them in the success.js and set the inpnut by tr.setInput('someTaskInput', process.env[shared.TestEnvVars.someTaskInput]). Okay that works but has a lot overhead.
Do you have better solution to make writing tests straight forward and easy?
